# Image Preview in dialog modal not working when loading content using ajax

Tags: php, html, ajax

```
<table id="result">
<a href='#' class='pop'><span class='fa fa-eye'><img src='image link here' style='display:none'></a>
</table>
```

The above href is used to open the image in modal.

```
Modal For Image Preview:
<div class="modal fade" id="imagemodal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="position:absolute">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
                <div class="modal-content">              
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span></button>
                    <img src="" class="imagepreview" style="width: 100%;" >
                </div>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
```

The below jquery (part1+part2) works in parent page but whenever the table content is loaded using ajax the preview is not working.

```
jQuery for modal show:
part1 : $(function() {
        $('.pop').on('click', function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            $('.imagepreview').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
            $('#imagemodal').modal('show');   
        });     
    });
```

part1 works in parent page.

```
Part2 :$("#results").on("click",".pop", function(){
        //alert("hello");
        e.preventDefault();
        $('.imagepreview1').attr('src', $(this).find('img').attr('src'));
        $('#imagemodal1').modal('show');
    });
```

part2 is also showing alert on click but image preview is not working.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could part of the problem be the class and id references in part 2? The class `imagepreview1` and ID `imagemodal1` don't exist in your examples. Should they be `imagepreview` and `imagemodal`?

What is going wrong? I gather that Part 2 isn't showing the image preview, but do you also have a problem with Part 1? If ajax is breaking your part 1, can you give a sample of your ajax loading?